# Typescript convert type with multiple string options to an array with those options as values

Tags: typescript

**From:**

`type status = "confirmed" | "pending" | "canceled"`

**To:**

`const statusArray = ["confirmed", "pending", "canceled"]`

---

**Context:** I have the type auto generated, yet I need to have them as array as well.

Comment: Impossible. The best you could do is check if an array contains all members of the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get a runtime value from a TypeScript type (but the other way around is definitely possible). The next best thing you can do is warn yourself if you forget to include a member of `status`. Here's 3 methods that I use, each with their own pros and cons.

Method 1: using permutations. This method is alright if your `status` type is very small (2-5) members. It gets quite slow for larger unions. However, it's the most direct; using it only needs an explicit type annotation. It also does not allow duplicates.

```
type Permutations<T extends string> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : {
    [K in T]: [K, ...Permutations<Exclude<T, K>>];
}[T];

type StatusArray = Permutations<status>;

const statusArray: StatusArray = ["confirmed", "pending", "canceled"];
```

Method 2: using a function. This works for all sizes of unions. In addition, it provides the most helpful error message. The only downside is that you need an ugly function call.

```
function createStatusArray<T extends status>(array: (status extends T ? T : { error: `Missing '${Exclude<status, T>}' from status` })[]) { return array; }

const statusArray = createStatusArray(["confirmed", "pending", "canceled"]);
```

Method 3: using an assertion. This also works for all sizes of unions. It may not provide the best error message, but it does error when you do not include all members of `status`. One downside is that you essentially need an extra variable declaration in order to retain the mutable array type.

```
const _statusArray = ["confirmed", "pending", "canceled"] as const;

type AssertStatusArray<T extends never = Exclude<status, typeof _statusArray[number]>> = T;

const statusArray = [..._statusArray];
```

[Playground (with all 3 methods)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAzsCGwCuMoF4oCIDGB7AdgGYCWATgLYQAmmUAPlpPlcfgOa0M7z7YQA21WgHphXVhAAexOBHzARwqHnKV5UXEmBRguWBGgRSpXKRgBYAFBX88SjDDw+UAKoxWbAApHyWxMQJUAG8rKDCdcGhvCj9gAPwYAB4AFSgpYDkqVDhSDwA+dCgAbWSAXTTJDOZUIvwIADcjcoB+YvKALigQy3De4oBpKFYoMs6i-oAaKAA6WejfBDjAxIBRSWx+JCoIFKn+vLzSgG5Q8IBfEuOrU7DQSCgAZUWUAEFjeBBC+dj4pLhEFB5E7WHrhPAJbT-ZAwN6kD6dJ4AmHvT4YIo4AgkChCKaYJgsdiYXHYHh8QQ0K6WM7XSy2eyOZwAdWIwAAFgAxJC8Jb4Lo3KCELnYHnKUgQRAQRHQ2EfFIVKpZWDPGB5AAU8BRnVVUJQ8syqFSrVSnSCaWMpk6AAMALIydzsKAAcgAJEE1hstjsdTApsk8mdHQKTOQlUjLVAzgBKIqlSNdKBi5CkXkauEgI4Rmm9cFwUPSlGFbBiiVS14o1Xo8FYyg0XH4jxErAk3gCISx4HUkF0iAOJzQADCgWALxgMCMIu62aHUAA+t6ZajihiiGQa428ZkG8TSa2KVB4Kgc8Bgfy7tAR2PSMBS8i03L0vqoHVGqRCu7NttEt6pmfcIRZ-OKK1Eg5AAEZNAchTJCeoJhEeeZlmmhRFLM0xzsqC6UmcQA)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, but you can create some helper function to check if the `statusArray` has all elements or not:

```
function expectAllAppear<Type>() {
  return function <T extends Type[]>(
    ...types: [Type] extends [T[number]] ? T : never
  ) {
    return types
  }
}

const expectAllStatusAppear = expectAllAppear<status>()

const statusArray = expectAllStatusAppear("confirmed", "pending", "canceled")
```

These functions are no-op actually, but if some elements don't appear in the arguments (eg. `expectAllStatusAppear("pending", "canceled")`), the type of the arguments will become `never` and cause type errors.

Answer (score 0):

As vr. has called it, you can't do it that way round. You can however, do it the other way round by starting with the concrete array and using `as const` like this:

```
const statusArray = ["confirmed", "pending", "canceled"] as const;

type StatusType = typeof statusArray[number];

const myStatus: StatusType = "confirmed";

const myOtherStatus: StatusType = "non_status";
// Type '"non_status"' is not assignable to type '"confirmed" | "pending" | "canceled"'.(2322)
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBNCGUCuECCAnd8CeMC8MA2gEShgBmAlugLYCmAJsQDQzEAOdYDlYA5izbB4YYHQA2jYgF0Y8CDDLQA3AChVUbJxgBlKIhQAVLXXwxNnEOTj7kaTDkJgkNAEZ100taqWwa2PQMIAC5dWyMTM1JwKlopb18YfwB5KAALD0C7UKyI7QJiMHAAfQQ7YjUAekqYY20AckKSspRiephKBSLYeQhKPjB4V0lzEHNIxrJY+iYYAB82Tm5eAXmhETFJJnqAOgAKACYAZgODgEogA)

Comment: Can't really do that when the type is *auto-generated*.

Comment: Thanks for _having my back_ on this one, stupid me